# Web Service Dates with timezone info

Tags: web-services, date, soap, asmx

I am quering a (.net) web service from Excel (*takes cover from the backlash*), which returns a array of dates. I have noticed that any date that is on the day boundry gets shifted forward 1 hour, I have checked the web service on the server and the original date is correct.

I then used Fiddler to view the call on the client machine, and the dates which are at midnight have a Z on the end (to mark it as UTC) where as all other date times don't.

**UPDATE The above statement is wrong, it is the first and last date that is marked with a Z, it doesn't matter what the time is. The rest is correct that the client only adjusts the first and last date**

I take it SOAP is then changing this from UTC to local (BST) and therefore adding an hour.

My question is how can I stop the Z from being added onto these dates (or change it to local)?

I have checked the culture in IIS 7.5 and it is set to en-GB, the server is set to UK.

Comment: Are you able to change the Web Service code on the server or is it only the Excel client that you have dev access to?

Comment: We have access to all, including the web server itself

Answer (score 1):

It's a little fiddly, and this isn't really an answer but should give you some things to try.

One way might be to  remove the offset. I don't have the code to had but in psudeo-like code it might be

```
TimeZone tz = GlobalizationNamespace.GetTimeZone("Greenwich Mean Time");
SomeDateTimeNoOffset = SomeDateTime.AddHours(tz.GetUtcOffset(SomeDateTime));
```

This should might stop the service from putting a Z at the end as it has no TimeZone offset.

Another other option would be to expose the property in the Service Contract as a String

```
public string DateTimeNoTzInfo
{
   get { DateTime.ToString('yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.ttttt') }
}
```

Comment: thanks Jaimal, I did think about the string option. I don't understand the first option but have found a solution which seems to work. Where ever I return a date I do Date.SpecifyKind(DateValue, DateTimeKind.Local) and it sends over 2012-04-30T12:50:49 +0100 which seems to be ok in the SOAP Client